# Capture entire iphone safari web page from MAC

Tags: java, ios, macos, safari, screenshot

Is it possible to capture iOS device/Simulator safari web page from MAC?

Now i am proceeding to writing automation for web page loading in safari. Need to capture screenshot for loading page.

Have tried with

```
driver =  new Augmenter().augment(driver);
    //Get the screenshot
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    System.out.println("Screenshot completed");
```

But came to know that it is not working in real device. So anyone please suggest how to capture device screenshot from MAC?

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/A6kAET0C7nc

For real iOS device, it is not possible to capture safari web page from mac using java code.